# Inserting Space into audio event in Flash

Tags: flash, audio

Is there a way to insert empty space into an audio event in Flash? For example, I have a narrator who didn't pause long enough, and I want to add some space without having to change the file in a separate program.

Answer (score 2):

There is no built in solution to do this.  You would have to create a cue-point system or just hack it by measuring the time it takes up to the point, pause the audio clip, then wait x number of milliseconds before continuing.  You are honestly better off fixing the original audio file in a sound editing program which is extremely easy to do.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your audio on the timeline, just scrub along to where you want the pause, then insert a few keyframes so that instead of one long sound event, you have two shorter ones. To edit the two resulting frame sounds, so that the first one ends at the pause and the second one starts afterwards, select the frame with the sound, and in the Property Inspector click the little pencil button next to "Effect". This gets you the "Edit sound envelope" dialog, which lets you change where your frame sound starts and stops, and you can apply changes to the volume as well. A very useful but often-overlooked feature.

If you're loading in the time and playing it with scripting, I'd go with Ralph's answer and hack in a fix to briefly pause the audio at a certain time (perhaps you could do this in a progress event handler on the sound itself). There are more robust ways you could do it, but they'd likely be more work than just editing the sound.